# How to fix the error - Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift

I'm highly new to swift and i ran across this error whilst listening to a course.

```
let savedString = ScoreLabel.text
let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(savedString,value(forKey: "Key"))
```

error -   Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
userDefaults.set(savedString, forKey: "Key")
```